# Semantic UI React

Tags: reactjs, jsx, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am using React and want to implement a tagging feature similar to that of this very site. I am using the Semantic UI Component library and they have this functionality built into their drop down component, where you can allow Additional values to be entered. Below is the code needed to accomplish this.

Normally the dropdown component is expecting some options to be passed, and the user can select from this list. The allowAdditional attribute allows the user to add their own value, which is then rendered client side. The problem is that i do not want to provide any options, as I want the user to be able to write custom tags (don't worry about my application of this). When giving no options, the library returns "No results found" in the dropdown.

Is there a way to remove the "No results found" or a way to do this within a different Semantic UI component? You should be able to throw the code into a code sandbox and debug if needed.

Any help would be awesome!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react'


class DropdownExampleAllowAdditions extends Component {
  state = { options: [] }

  handleAddition = (e, { value }) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      options: [{ text: value, value }, ...prevState.options],
    }))
    console.log(this.state)
  }

  handleChange = (e, { value }) => this.setState({ key: value })

  render() {
    const { key } = this.state

    return (
      <Dropdown
        options={this.state.options}
        placeholder='Enter a Value'
        search
        selection
        fluid
        multiple
        allowAdditions
        value={key}
        onAddItem={this.handleAddition}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    )
  }
}

export default DropdownExampleAllowAdditions
```

Answer (score 3):

Ahh, some lazy programming:

The dropdown API has the `noResultsMessage` attribute, which can be used to handle when there are no results